# Update database from service, then handle changes in activity - how?

Tags: android, android-service, android-sqlite, android-service-binding

I have a simple messaging app.
It uses STOMP over Websockets to receive data (messages) from server.

I want to move all websockets stuff to Service that I could bind to my activity to send messages through it.

With Binder I can run Service methods in Activity, so sending messages not a problem. Problem is to receive messages and put them to Activity's view.

I want to do that with local database, like that:

1. Service receives message from STOMP
2. Service puts that message in local Database
3. Activity in some way understands that there are new message in database and puts it to ListView (with CursorAdapter?).

How can I achieve that? Maybe I need something like using SAME database ContentResolver in Activity and in a Service?

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast message When you receive message from websocket.
So, Call this method from your service.

```
private void broadcastNotification(Context context){
    Intent intent = new Intent("NOTIFICATION");
    intent.putExtra("MESSAGE", "your_message");
    context.sendBroadcast(intent);        
}
```

Register Broadcast Receiver in your activity.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mContext.registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver, new   IntentFilter("NOTIFICATION"));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    stopService();
    mContext.unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}

private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Update the Activity
    }
}
```

So whenever you receive message from websocket, Store it to database and broadcast the message and listen it in activity. When OnReceive Method in your activity call do your activity update task.

Comment: Yes, I know that way. But I don't think it's a really good way. 
Suppose that I have 15 active chats and every chat receiving one message per second. So we have 15 Broadcasts in every seconds. I think that problem can be solved by using ContentProviders or something like that, but don't know how.

Comment: You can use the same broadcast for all 15 thread. What you can do is set different intent action for each active chat and in OnReceive method based on intent action you can identify from which active chat the message arrive.

Comment: Yep. Actually, "destination" ChatID is contained in STOMP message header and I have only one Websockets thread. But is using Broadcasts for every new message _really the best_ way to do it?

Comment: @udenfox May be "LocalBroadcastManager" is best for you. It's also more efficient than a normal BroadcastReceiver. But your broadcast does not need to target anything outside your app.